# How to determine if a user has closed his tab in order to fire a socket.io emit event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

Currently I'm trying to learn Socket.IO and in order to do that I've decided to try and build a chat application. Right now I have a functioning chat and I'm trying to create a list to the side of the chat that displays the usernames of all connected people.

When the user visits the page, an input field asks for a username. When a username is typed and submitted, this function executes:

```
setUsername(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    this.username = this.usernameInput
    this.usernameInput = null
    this.socket.emit('userJoined', this.username)
}
```

The function sets `this.username` to the inputted username and then emits that a user with `this.username` has joined and then this function pushes it to the array of online users:

```
this.socket.on('userJoined', (user) => {
    this.onlineUsers.push(user)
});
```

So far so good, when users join the chat, their usernames do go inside the onlineUsers array, however, I can't figure out how to remove them out of this array when they close their tab. In order to do that I'd have to fire `this.socket.emit('userLeft', this.username)` but I am not sure how am I supposed to fire it. Is there a function in which I can put this code that is always executed when a user closes his tab?

I've supplied my full code below:

```
<template>
    <div class="home">
        {{ onlineUsers }}
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class='username-container' v-if='!this.username'>
                <form class='username-form' @submit='setUsername($event)'>
                    <input class='username-input' v-model="usernameInput" placeholder="Pick a username">
                    <div class='enter-chat' @click='setUsername($event)'>Enter chat</div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class='chat-container' v-else>
                <div class="chat">
                    <div class="messages">
                        <div class='message-container' v-for='message in messages'>
                            <div class="username-date-container">
                                <p class='username'>{{ message.username }}</p>
                                <p class='date'>{{ getTimeAndDate(message.time) }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <p class='message'>{{ message.message }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form @submit='sendMessage($event)'>
                    <input class='message-input' v-model="message" placeholder="Type a message">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import io from 'socket.io-client'
    import moment from 'moment'

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                socket: io.connect('http://localhost:3000'),
                usernameInput: null,
                username: null,
                messages: [],
                message: null,
                onlineUsers: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setUsername(event){
                event.preventDefault()
                this.username = this.usernameInput
                this.usernameInput = null
                this.socket.emit('userJoined', this.username)
            },
            sendMessage(event){
                event.preventDefault()
                let fullMessage = {
                    username: this.username,
                    message: this.message,
                    time: Date.now()
                }
                this.socket.emit('message', fullMessage)
                this.message = null
            },
            getTimeAndDate(timestamp){
                return moment(timestamp).subtract(10, 'days').calendar();
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.socket.on('message', (message) => {
                this.messages.push(message)
            });
            this.socket.on('userJoined', (user) => {
                this.onlineUsers.push(user)
            });
            this.socket.on('userLeft', (user) => {
                this.onlineUsers.pop(user)
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: An alternate solution that may be more resilient would be to (also) handle the socket [disconnect event](https://socket.io/docs/#Disconnection-detection) on the server side, if you can. This way, even if something happens on the client side and you don't get the event from the client, you can maintain the proper state on the server. If a user has no socket connections, then they obviously left.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) { ... });
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) { ... };
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a very solid solution using a Map.

**All Server-Side**:

```
import type { NextApiRequest } from 'next'
import type { ClientToServerEvents, InterServerEvents, NextApiResponseWithSocket, ServerToClientEvents, SocketData } from '../../types/socket'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'

let socketsData = new Map()

const socket = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponseWithSocket) => {
  // socket initialisation, blah blah blah

  io.on('connection', socket => {
    // all the other events you need (`sendMessage`, `createRoom` and so on)

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      const { username, roomId } = socketsData.get(socket.id)
      io.to(roomId).emit('userLeft', `${username} has left the room`)
      socketsData.delete(socket.id)
    })
  })

  res.status(200).send('Setting up the socket.')
}

export default socket
```

As you can see, if you need something socket-specific, you can store all the data in a map.